# Radio Buttons for shipping options are not activated on cart page

Tags: woocommerce, radio-button, cart

I have multiple shipping options to choose from that display on the cart page in woocommerce, however they are not clickable until you proceed to checkout. What hook/code can I add to activate the shipping option radio buttons on the cart page so people can choose expedited shipping and see the total before proceeding to checkout.

Comment: Do you have the shipping calculator enabled on cart page from WooCommerce settings?

Comment: They don't work either way on the cart page. I have tried both options with Calculator enabled and disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to be able to grab the user's location before shipping options are able to be figured out. What you want to do is in the main WC settings area go to "Default customer location." From there you can choose from one of the following:

- **Shop base address** tells the system to assume they are in the same location as your shop.
- **No address** gives them no location, and no taxes are calculated.
- **Geolocate address** verifies where their current location and calculate taxes accordingly.
- **Geolocate with page caching support** is the same as above, but does the geolocation via Ajax. You may notice your website URLs have a ?v=xxxxx appended to them. This is normal to prevent static caching of prices.

Reference: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/

Comment: Hmm - OK well not sure why but no matter what settings I choose they still do not allow you to click on them to change between the different shipping options until proceeding to checkout.

Comment: Do you have multiple shipping methods per zone?

Comment: I have local pick up, flat rate & weight based shipping. There are 2 classes and above 24lbs needs to go to weight based. BUT then run into needing to hide the flat rate once the cart goes over 24lbs. Thinking I could use a hook to do this. I found this code but dont know how to modify it for what I am needing. do you?

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_class_is_in_cart', 10, 2 );
 
function hide_shipping_when_class_is_in_cart( $rates, $package ) {
    // shipping class IDs that need the method removed
    $shipping_classes = array(1111,2232,4235);
    $if_exists = false;
 
    foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values )
        if( in_array( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id(), $shipping_classes ) )
            $if_exists = true;
 
    if( $if_exists ) unset( $rates['free_shipping'] );
 
    return $rates;
}